# How to split string delimited with "-"  into different strings?

Tags: c#, string, delimiter

I have a string in the following format:

```
string1-string2-string3
```

I want to be able to get 3 strings out of this.  How do I do that?

Comment: Did you look at String.Split()??

Comment: I don't get the downvoters on this. A legitimate question, perhaps the OP didn't know about String.Split ?

Comment: Probably OP is a newbie with C#, but that doesn't mean we have to punish him! I agree with @driis: I think it's wrong to downvote this legitimate question

Comment: @driis - agreed. "Too easy" is not a reason for downvotes.

Comment: @driis - A question shows 0 attempt at research. Just looking at the documentation for `string` would be enough.

Comment: @driis : I also do not downvoted but think that before asking such a simple question (I believe OP felt that solutions would be pretty simple) OP should try seacrh, you know there are tons of such `String.Split` questions, moreover I believe this is bad practice to answer such 100-times duplicated simple questions

Comment: @sll - IMO in that case the question should be closed as duplicate rather than downvoted.

Comment: @Yakimych : ABSOLUTELY, because this is pretty find and should be appreciated when people asking questions even so simple, so DOWNVOTED should be a system which advice to search before asking new question because it is obvious that people lazy to search manually

Answer (score 7):

```
string[] words = s.Split('-');

foreach (string word in words)
{
     Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string[] parts = yourString.Split('-');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.Split: `string1.Split('-');`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
yorString.Split('-')
```

Comment: Actually, this one won't work, the parameter is char[] or string[], and only the char one is a `params char[]` parameter.